# Undefined reference: ref points to section instead of table in Appendix

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, captions, labels, appendices

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm having some troubles getting the correct reference to tables in the Appendix. I have used the `\label` after `\caption` and it still doesn't work. But when I remove `\appendix`, the table gets the correct label (instead of the section number). The output of `\ref{}` is "A.8 lists..." whereas it should be "Appendix A lists...".

Here's my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\UseRawInputEncoding
\usepackage{lineno, hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[tableposition=t]{caption}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{comment}

\clearpage
%Appendix
\appendix

\section{Selected primary studies in the review.}

%% Table 11
{\footnotesize\sffamily
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.2\hsize}L
                             >{\hsize=1.9\hsize}L
                             >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L
                             >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}L
                             >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}L}
\caption{Selected primary studies in the review.}
\label{tab:studieslist}\\
    \toprule
\textbf{ID}  & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{Venue} & \textbf{Year} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
   \toprule
\textbf{ID}  & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Author(s)} & \textbf{Venue} & \textbf{Year} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
\endfoot
P1 & Computer security & G. Post & Information and Software Technology & 2003  \\
\addlinespace
```

And I refer to this table like this:

```
\ref{tab:studieslist} lists the...
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete (compilable) small document.

Comment: The main issue is that the `\caption` and `\label` statements *must* occur inside a `table` environment; this doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: Aside: What are the `longtable` macros `\endfirsthead`, `\endhead`, and `\endfoot` doing inside a `tabularx` environment?

Comment: @Mico, I'm sorry, I don't understand it much, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Please, for start read https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables. So far you have wrong mix of `xtabular` table (which is usual use in `table` float environment) in which you use syntax from `longtable` intended for multipage table (which should not be inside `table` float). If your table is longer than one page and you like to use column specifications of `tabularx`, than you should use `xltabular` or `ltablex` packages.

Comment: @Zarko: OP uses `ltablex` which changes the behaviour of `tabularx` to also break across pages. The used syntax is thus correct.

Comment: @Nez: If I take your code, add the missing `\begin{document}`, `}`, `\end{document}` and `\ref{tab:studieslist}` in order to make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), I get the expected ouptput:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zrr8.png The `\ref` command returnd "A1" since this is the number of the table in which you used the corresponding `\label` command in. [...]

Comment: [...] If you want the `\ref` command to return "Appendix A" instead, add a `\label` to your `\section` command as in `\section{Selected primary studies in the review.} \label{sec:myappendix}`. Using `\ref{sec:myappendix}` will then return the expected "Appendix A".

Comment: @leandriis: Thank you very much. Yes, it does solve the problem. But I'm still confused why I get that A.1 as the label of the table. I use this format for tables throughout the document and the others worked (i.e., cross-referencing the tables).

Comment: @Nez: What do you expect instead of "A 1" here?

Comment: @leandriis, Table x instead of Table x.A

Comment: @Nez: Your table is in the appendix of your document. Thus the "A"  is added.

Comment: @leandriis Oh, I see. I thought there's a way to remove that from the table name. My bad. Thanks!

Comment: @Nez: Since you use a journal's documentclass, I assume you prepare a paper you want to submit to one of this publisher's journals. If that's teh case, don't change the default output yu get.

Comment: @leandriis, in time when I wrote my comment, it was not known that `ltablex` is used.